# Logcat Screen Record with Huawei

Tags: android, logcat, huawei-mobile-services, screen-recording

Using logcat **screen record** with Sony Xperia D2303, Samsung Galaxy Tab 10, Asus ZenPad z170 without any problem, I cannot manage to make it work with **Huawei Y6 2017**. It stays grayed. The screenshot function works, the logcat is readable, though. I tried to switch to Engineer Mode with dialing the following code : `*#*#2846579#*#*` with no success. Menu pops up, but nothing really helps. Could anyone have some experience with this ?

Comment: did you find how to screen record using logcat?